# OSX Writeroom like focus mode for other apps?

Tags: macos, productivity, fullscreen

I like the way [WriteRoom](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/writeroom) let's you focus on writing. Screen black: only a prompt. Is there a OSX utility that makes the same focus mode available to other app. For instance when you are writing an e-mail or iTunes it blacks out the rest of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

Press `Cmd-Option-H` to hide all other applications. Switch applications by `Option-Clicking` the new application's Dock icon to hide the previous application.

---

Always hide background applications by using tools such as [Backdrop](http://www.johnhaney.com/backdrop/) or [Doodim](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/products/doodim/).

---

Dim or hide the  menubar by using [Menushade](http://www.nullriver.com/products).

---

Since OS X Lion, most applications can be made full screen, usually by pressing `Cmd-Ctrl-F`.